# Webview not showing the desired Result

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-webview

Trying to implement webview. But nothing appears except white screen.

Fragment contains this

```
View view;
private WebView webView;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview_nav);


    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");


    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    return view;
}
```

calling Fragments from mainactivity like this

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragment_nav fragment_nav = new fragment_nav();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment_nav);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Fragment Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Black"
>


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong. Because when I'm doing the same thing in another project it works. But not in this project.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because there are few ways you can implement the webview

Comment: I am trying to show google map using webview as soon as navigation button is clicked